# Remove oxford comma on title page in German apa7

Tags: titles, punctuation, german, apa7

I'm using the apa7 package in LaTeX. In the German language, we do not have the oxford comma (eg. "**,** and") when we list multiple authors. However, even with babel set to ngerman, I get an oxford comma at the authors names on my title page. I have not found any possibilities to remove it and I do not want to edit the pdf after generation by hand.

[image: screenshot of title page]

I want it to say "John Doe, John Doe, John Doe und John Doe" **without** the comma.

Minimal working sample attached:

```
\documentclass[12pt, stu, a4paper, floatsintext]{apa7}

%Referenzen für Titelseite
\authorsnames{John Doe, John Doe, John Doe, John Doe}
\title{This is the title.}
\date{17.03.2023}
\duedate{17.03.2023}
\professor{Prof. Dr. Jane Doe}
\course{Course Name}
\authorsaffiliations{University of test}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: In English also, if a list is more than two items the last " and" does not have to be preceded by a comma.

Comment: @yannisl That's not the Oxford comma rule though.

Comment: @AlanMunn True. Depends on the country and Style Book you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can patch the `\displayauthors` command.  Since there are two places in that command which define the `\prelastauthorsep` command, we patch the same command twice.

```
\documentclass[12pt, stu, a4paper, floatsintext]{apa7}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\displayauthors}{{\prelastauthorsep}{,}}{{\prelastauthorsep}{}}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd{\displayauthors}{{\prelastauthorsep}{,}}{{\prelastauthorsep}{}}{}{\fail}
%Referenzen für Titelseite
\authorsnames{John Doe, John Doe, John Doe, John Doe}
\title{This is the title.}
\date{17.03.2023}
\duedate{17.03.2023}
\professor{Prof. Dr. Jane Doe}
\course{Course Name}
\authorsaffiliations{University of test}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: That absolutely worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, would you mind me asking how you've come to that solution? I'm still kind of new to LaTeX and and I want to understand more about how to solve these kind of issues by myself.

Comment: @JonathanF Well it starts by opening the code for the class `kpsewhich apa7.cls` gives you the full path. Then I browsed the code for macros relating to `author` and found the `\prelastauthorsep` macro, which was clearly the relevant one to change. But that macro is redefined inside the `\displayauthors` macro, and so that's the macro that needed patched. The `etoolbox` package provides excellent tools for patching which is much cleaner than redefining the whole macro inside the document.